# jQuery draggable widget not firing drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a simple problem, or so it seems, with jQuery UI's draggable widget.  The draggable widget has a drag event, which is fired whenever the mouse drags the draggable element on the page.  Simple, no?  This code doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.draggable').draggable({
                drag:function(){
                    alert(1); // simple alert, nothing happens
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="draggable">drag me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on why this isn't firing? I'm using:

- jquery-1.9.1.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.10.3

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Comment: If you are trying to capture the drag, try start/stop funcitons.

Comment: Did you try putting arguments in you callback function like in the API?  Don't think it will make a difference but you never know.

Comment: Did you get any javascript issue?check in firebug console

Comment: It should work. Can you past all your code?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty bad mistake on my part.  Google Chrome allowed me to check the "Do not let this page alert me again" option.  I must have checked it once.  But on all subsequent reloads of the page, the setting was kept.  It wasn't until this morning that it worked again.  This is a good post, while a bit silly, it will help someone.  There should be some kind of notice of this somewhere, at least for us devs.

I thought this option was per request, but it is per session.

Comment: Ha! I've been bitten by that one before. Moral of the story? Use console.logs unless you REALLY must use an alert.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem, unless you have done some other mistake somewhere. Your code works fine. See the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/525Js/

I have placed your HTML code in fiddle with needed modifications:

HTML panel:

```
<div class="draggable">drag me</div>
```

JS panel:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.draggable').draggable({
            drag:function(){
                alert(1); // simple alert, nothing happens
            }
        });
    });
```